# Row counts groupby multiple columns for NUMPY array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array as the following:

```
arr =[['a', '1' ,'2.3'],
['a', '1' ,'1.1'],
['b', '2', '3.4'],
['a', '2', '10.1']]
```

I would like to get row counts groupby the first and the second column [0,1].

I am expecting the following:

```
arr_counts = [['a', '1', 2],
['b', '2', 1],
['a', '2', 1]]
```

I known this can be done easily using PANDAS. But I would like to stay in NUMPY array. #So, no PANDAS please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `np.unique` + `np.column_stack` combination:

```
arr_counts = np.column_stack(np.unique(arr[:, :2], axis=0, return_counts=True))
```

---

```
array([['a', '1', '2'],
       ['a', '2', '1'],
       ['b', '2', '1']], dtype='<U21')
```

Comment: Thank you very much RomanPerekhrest! Perfect answer!